# Unchanged Conjugate Radical? (Rationalizing Demoninators)

Tags: radicals, nested-radicals, rationalising-denominator

I'm on one of the more difficult practice problems on Excercise 1-6 in "AoPS:Vol. 1".

[Problem £4 : Ex. 1-6. The hint details that we should multiply $$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 1 \sqrt 2}\right) $$ by it's conjugate which the hint identifies as itself.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d77CG.png)

I have tried rationalizing the above fraction by multiplying it's conjugate by itself, however, how can we FOIL the two terms when there appears to only be one?

**Overall Questions:**
1. How the Conjugate Radical be the same as the original expression? If so, why?
2. How can we rationalize a fraction like this which appears to have only one term, when rationalization by conjugate radicals always requires two?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1/\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}/(1+\sqrt{2})$.

Now multiply top and bottom by $1-\sqrt(2)$.

$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}(1-\sqrt(2))/((1-\sqrt(2))((1+\sqrt{2}))$

$=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}(1-\sqrt(2))/(-1)$

$=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}(\sqrt(2)-1)$

Comment: Hmmm,... I seem to be having issues from the very first step! How do we go from the first step to the second one? How does the denominator become (1+sqrt(2)) in the second step? Did we multiply by a conjugate, or...?

Comment: @RefathBari: No, XSPX multiplied both the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$ to obtain $\frac {\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}}{1+\sqrt{2}}$